# How can I install ROS Noetic in Ubuntu 20.04 using trusted GPG?

Tags: bash, file, ubuntu, installation, ros

I am trying to install ROS Noetic in Ubuntu 20.04.6, but when I set the keys I get the following warning:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8))
```

which then leads to the following print when I run `$ sudo apt update`:

```
...
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any suggestions? I don't know which specific code do I have to use to set the keys using trusted.gpg.

I am using the following commands:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
```

Comment: Didn't you get a message when installing your ubuntu OS about [ubuntu.se] ? Please delete here and post there. Good luck.